# _reactDom2.default.render error on using ReactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I'm using ReactDOM.render, I'm getting the following error: `_reactDom2.default.render`. But when I'm using React.render, I'm not getting any errors and the files are executed perfectly.

My issue is closely related to this: http://discuss.babeljs.io/t/babel-5-6-with-react-throwing-error-when-trying-to-render-iframes/158

Comment: What you posted is not an error. Are you getting an actual error message somewhere like the browser console?

Comment: Can you post react-dom definition it should be like this `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` correct?

Comment: Yes. I'm doing `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

Comment: This is the exact error: `Uncaught TypeError: _reactDom2.default.render is not a function`

Comment: God damn, this is exactly my errors and no answer...

Comment: I think its just old crappy code in my case. I'm rewriting a lot of stuff and updating libraries from 2 years ago.